# Flash Builder 4.6 - Releasing build "Error occured while packaging the application"

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder

I have a simple project I wrote targeting iOS using FB 4.6

While I'm debuging and Running it - It works perfectly.

The only problem is when I'm trying to Release a build I get the following error:

> "Error occured while packaging the application:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
>   ........."

Any idea's how to find the cause for this failure?

http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-4288283-178899/error_fb46.png - print screen

Thanks 
Guy.